# How do you move the text anchor in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, text

There is a very nice way of including Inkscape graphics in LateX files such that Latex renders the text from the image. [Here is the description.](http://ctan.cs.uu.nl/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf)

Now [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2107/167361) already describes how the text is positioned. Unfortunately it just treats aligning the text left, center and right which will move the anchor. However, due to the nature of my illustration I need the anchor to be at the top. How can I get there?

In images:

I have:
[image: have]
I want:
[image]

Comment: Inkscape doesn't provide that option. The text anchor is always at the bottom. Its purpose is for aligning multiple texts with each other by indicating the baseline of the text. So, if you want to align the top of the text with something, use the Align and Distribute dialog, or use guides that you position a bit below the place where the top is intended to be.

Comment: @Moini - actually there is a way to do it.

Comment: @BillyKerr Mmh, yes, hadn't thought of using vertical shift for it... I was thinking along using some 'official' value for the text (e.g. the ascender height, cap height...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to do that, other than perhaps for snapping, but it is possible.

Highlight the text and change the vertical shift.

[image]

Comment: Well, for the reason mentioned above. It's helpful for when Latex replaces the text. :)